# como redondeo un resultado de división?

Tags: redondeo, division

tengo este calculo en Javascript:

```
ingresostt = parseInt($('#ingresostt').val());
relacionci = parseInt(cuotafinalRefi) / parseInt(ingresostt) *100;
$('#relacionci').val(relacionci);
```

No sé como hacer para que el resultado quede en 2 digitos, ejemplo % 24,01

Si me pueden ayudar... gracias

Comment: `relacionci.toFixed(2)` el número entre paréntesis es la cantidad de decimales a aparecer

Comment: Disculpa, no se donde debo agregar esta opción..

Comment: A la variable que le pasas como argumento a la función val, prueba ahi